# Cannot upload files from my local subversion directory into the subversion repository

Tags: svn

Subversion reports this error:

```
MKActivity of
'/RAVI/HDR/TestandRelease/!svn/act/d...:
authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server:
rejected Basic
```

Comment: Ravi, I can't answer, but you may want to edit the question and provide more information about the problem.  What exactly did you do to get this error?

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of what happened? What OS are you using? What version of Subversion is your client? When did you get this error? Can you checkout from this server? Can you use `svn ls` from this machine?

Comment: Looks like incorrect password is the cause.

Comment: What SVN client you are using? If TortoiseSVN, then please try clearing the authentication information in cache and try your SVN commit again. If it gets error again, then your account may not be having enough permissions to commit in this folder I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wording of the error is incomplete. There should be more information after `Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic`.

I guess that the full error is `Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge`. In such case, the root cause is invalid password.